# I got this error while creating a new Laravel project -> Laravel new projectName

Tags: laravel

[CLICK HERE to look the SCREENSHOT of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP1ZK.png)

I am creating a new Laravel project by using following command, Laravel new projectName

Answer (score 0):

your php version is lower than what laravel 9 has required.
you need to upgrade your php to version 8 and above .

see the instruction below

https://wecode101.com/upgrade-xampp-from-php-7-to-8-windows-10

hope that would work for you .

Comment: Thank You for you response . But my PHP version is already PHP 8.0.15 (cli).

Comment: so when you try to run php --version command , you will get php version 8 ?

Comment: yes , when i run php --version on my cmd , its gives me PHP 8.0.15(cli) .

Comment: i am struggling to solve this since two days. i am actually following the YouTube Video , but mine is not working as it shows in the Tutorials video here is the link to the tutorial 

 https://youtu.be/ImtZ5yENzgE?t=309